# C++ searching for a phrase in a file with UCS-2 LE encoding

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ucs2

I need to write a program that searches a text file and makes a list of names, that this file is contains. Every name is placed after "[PRG]" phrase. So I want to search for "PRG" and than read next word. I have a problem though, because encoding of this file is UCS-2 LE. I found out that instead of "string" I need to use "wstring" variables. But I see that I'm reading strange values form my file and I cannot compare them with "PRG" phrase.

Here is the code:

```
int main() {
wstring textBuff; // Buffor for reading text from a file
wstring searchBuff = L"PRG"; // Variable containing searching phrase

wifstream file;
file.open("programs.prg", ios::in | ios::binary);

if (file.good()) {
    // Reading file and listing every word after "PRG" phrase
    while (!file.eof()) {
        file >> textBuff;
        if (textBuff.find(searchBuff) != string::npos)
            wcout << textBuff << endl;
    }
}
file.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I'm new to programming, so I'm sorry if my question is trivial, but I'm stuck and I have no idea what else can I do. 
Thank you in advance.

Here is the prg file I'm trying to get data from:
[.prg file](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=programs.prg)

It contains bunch of other data, but what I want to do is to make list of names of baking programs. So i want to search for [PRG], than read two another words and than get rest of the line, which is name of the baking programme.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a copy of data from your file or some data with great similarity it is difficult to help much.

A number of issues arise and I suspect that any of them could matter since you call yourself "new to programming".

Start by doing some research reading at http://hackipedia.org/Character%20sets/Unicode,%20UTF%20and%20UCS%20encodings/UCS-2.htm

Especially the section titled:
Byte order encoding schemes

If your data has a BOM after the "PRG" label then you would have to deal with that by coding for the appropriate endianess...

Also read up on the material at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771556.aspx

Especially the note at the bottom...

Dr t

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I added the file to my main post. After debugging the program I see that first value is " 'ÿ','þ','[','\0','T''\0','Y','\0','P','\0'']' " instead of just "[TYP]". I guess that first two characters must be BOM, but I don't really know what I can do about that. Is there any way to get rid of them? I just need the "find" function to work. It's the only part of this program that doesn't work.